# Reference for short time existence of paraobolic PDE on bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

I am looking for a reference treating parabolic equations on vector bundles. In particular, I look for precise conditions which guarantee short time existence. I found it quoted at different places in the literature as standard fact for parabolic PDEs.

The concrete PDE in which I am interested has the following shape:
$$\partial_t h = - ( \Delta_A h + f(h, d_A h) ),\quad h_0 = 1$$
Here $h \in \Omega^0(\Sigma, \text{End}(E))$ is a section the endomorphism bundle of a vector bundle $E$ over a Riemann surface $\Sigma$ and $A$ some fixed connection on $E$. The term $f$ is a non-linear function in $h$ and its first order derivatives.

The RHS is an (uniformly) elliptic operator on $\Omega^0(\Sigma, E)$. Is ellipticity on the RHS in general enough to guarantee short time existence?

Comment: I used to look for the same thing in mathoverflow, and I found this post helpful: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99994/short-time-existence-on-nonlinear-parabolic-pde