# Short time existence for fully nonlinear parabolic equations

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

I am trying to assert short time existence for a fully nonlinear equation of the general form

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u_t = F(x,u,Du,D^2u) & \text{in }(0,T)\times\Omega\\
u(\cdot,0) = u_0(\cdot) & \text{in }\Omega \\
u(x,t) = 1 & \text{on }(0,T)\times\partial\Omega
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $u_0$ is smooth, $F=F(x,z,p,A)$ is smooth in all entries and concave in $A$, and $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth bounded domain. I know that the initial data is uniformly elliptic, in the sense that there are constants $0<c\leq C <\infty$ such that linearization of $F$ at $u_0$ satisfies

\begin{equation}
c\delta^{ij} \leq \frac{\partial F}{\partial A_{ij}}(x,u_0(x), Du_0(x), D^2 u_0(x)) \leq C\delta^{ij}\quad\text{ for all }x\in\Omega
\end{equation}

in the sense of matrices. My question is whether one can conclude short time existence immediately, using uniform parabolicity at time $t=0$ and the implicit function theorem, or whether one also needs *a priori* estimates. I have been unable to find a reference in this level of generality, and all the papers I have read seem to gloss over this issue.

Thanks in advance!

(By the way, I am aware of the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99994/short-time-existence-on-nonlinear-parabolic-pde), although I still can't gauge from the answer there what goes into the proof in the fully nonlinear case. The specific example given is parabolic Monge-Ampere with convex initial data, but is it solely the convex initial data that yields short time existence, or the fact this also enables us to prove *a priori* estimates?)

Comment: I think that you should assume that $F$ is an increasing function of $A$. Concavity might be important, but monotonicity is of course much more. Think to the linear case !

Comment: Whenever you have any kind of estimates for the problem as linearized around an open set of functions, it should be automatically possible to appeal to Hamilton's Nash-Moser theorem. And then the nonlinear estimates automatically follow. But this must be an overcomplication for the specific problem you are asking

Comment: Also see Huisken and Polden's article "Geometric evolution equations for hypersurfaces" for a careful treatment of quasilinear evolution equations of arbitrary order on a manifold

Comment: Possibly Lieberman's book "Second order parabolic differential equations" is where you want to look

Answer (score 3):

Some years ago we had a similar difficulty in finding results on fully nonlinear parabolic problems. Maybe these topics fell out of fashion before anybody wrote a reasonably complete wrap-up of known results. Anyway, you might find something in our joint paper [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002080050114). Actually, we consider weakly parabolic systems (i.e., the elliptic part may be degenerate) which leads to some unexpected phenomena.